# Delete and edit users with ASP.NET Identity using GridView's RowCommand?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, asp.net-identity

I have a `GridView` that is bound to `AspNetUsers` via an `SqlDataSource`.  I am trying to implement the `GridView_RowCommand` to delete and edit/update users, but I can't figure out how to do it via the ASP.NET Identity API.  I have extended `IdentityUser` with a class called `ApplicationUser` and my DB Context is called `ApplicationDBContext`.
When I click delete or edit on a GridView row, how can I delete or update the user given the selected user.

This is what I have so far, but its basically nothing:

```
    protected void Users_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
        {
          //How do I delete?

        }
        else if(e.CommandName == "Edit")
        {
            How do I Update?
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example I have put together, I do not have Visual Studio so it may not be 100% but it's close enough for your purposes I would say:

```
protected void Users_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Users.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);
        ApplicationUser user = (ApplicationUser)IdentityManager.Store.Users.FindAsync(id, CancellationToken.None);
        using (ApplicationDbContext dbcontext = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            dbcontext.UserLogins.RemoveRange(dbcontext.UserLogins.Where(ul => ul.UserId == user.Id));
            dbcontext.UserRoles.RemoveRange(dbcontext.UserRoles.Where(ur => ur.UserId == user.Id));
            dbcontext.UserSecrets.RemoveRange(dbcontext.UserSecrets.Where(us => us.UserName == user.UserName));
            dbcontext.UserManagement.RemoveRange(dbcontext.UserManagement.Where(um => um.UserId == user.Id));
            dbcontext.Users.Remove(dbcontext.Users.Where(usr => usr.Id == user.Id).Single());
            dbcontext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is cascading going on, so it is pointless to have to delete from a bunch of tables.

Answer (score -1):

At first I tried the GridView's RowCommand which was fired, but then I just ended up specifying the DeleteCommand and UpdateCommand on the SqlDataSource and that solved the problem.

The only change was made when I configured the SqlDataSource which produce the following markup which in turn made things work:

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="UsersSqlDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>"
                    SelectCommand="SELECT [Id], [UserName], [FirstName], [LastName], [Email] FROM [AspNetUsers]"
                    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [AspNetUsers] WHERE [Id] = @Id"
                    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [AspNetUsers] ([Id], [UserName], [FirstName], [LastName], [Email]) VALUES (@Id, @UserName, @FirstName, @LastName, @Email)"
                    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [AspNetUsers] SET [UserName] = @UserName, [FirstName] = @FirstName, [LastName] = @LastName, [Email] = @Email WHERE [Id] = @Id">
                    <DeleteParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="String" />
                    </DeleteParameters>
                    <InsertParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="UserName" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
                    </InsertParameters>
                    <UpdateParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="UserName" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="String" />
                    </UpdateParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: In your original question you never said the code wasn't executing.. you just asked: "How to I delete/update". Also, since this is the answer, where is the code you changed to fix your problem so that anyone that comes across this question may actually get something out of it.

Comment: @Seany84 - my post was updated. As you can see, only markup was automatically created after I configured the SqlDataSource through a wizard.  It just asked if I wanted to create inert, upate, and delete for me.

Comment: That's better, at least other people who come across this thread will take something out of it. I still don't believe that the title of the question matches your answer.